# Не правильно работает matcher java

Tags: java, html, регулярные-выражения

Есть HTML-шаблон письма и регулярное выражение, которое работает на [regex101.com](http://regex101.com). С его помощью вместо указанных переменных в формате `%name%` подставляются необходимые значения. У меня таких переменных несколько в документе.

Проблема в том что `Matcher` берет первый и последний `%` и якобы это одно найденное совпадение по регулярному выражению.

Само регулярное выражение выглядит так: `%([a-z].+)%`. Самое интересное, что на [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) всё нормально работает, а в коде нет.

Подскажите решение.

Comment: Используйте `%([a-z]+)%`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Спасибо. помогло.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Шаблон `.+` находит 1 и более символов, отличных от символов перевода строки. Так как `+` - "жадный" квантификатор, в совпадении сохраняется последовательность знаков от самого левого до самого правого в строке.

Удалите `.+` и используйте

```
%([a-z]+)%
```

- `%` - символ процента
- `([a-z]+)` - захватывающая группа (подмаска), находящее 1 и более строчных букв ASCII
- `%` - символ процента